# Cocos2d: How to add momentum when moving sprites with touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Im moving a sprite in my app with this code:

```
- (void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
    oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
    oldTouchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldTouchLocation];

    CGPoint translation = ccpSub(touchLocation, oldTouchLocation);
    CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(self.position, translation);

    self.position = newPos;
}
```

It works fine, but the sprite moves as the finder is on the screen.

What I want to achieve is some sort of momentum after the swipe, 
like in the build in apps in iOS.

Can anyone give me a hint of how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply get the speed (in px per second) when you let the object go,

```
(thisTouchPosition.x - lastTouchPosition.x) / (thisTouchTime - lastTouchTime)
```

Then make a scale factor for the "slowdown" (also in px per second 0.0-1.0) you want the object to have when released.  The lower the SLOWDOWN the faster the slowdown.  And in your render loop something like this for your position should work.  FPS is your cycle rate.

```
SPEED *= SLOWDOWN
x = x + SPEED / FPS
```

If you don't have a render loop (you should though) then you will need to make an NSTimer and invalidate it when its done or spawn another thread to do this.

This is untested, but should get you going.

Comment: In addition, make sure you reset SPEED to 0 when it falls below a certain (small) threshold to avoid a jagged-looking animation at below-pixel speeds.

Comment: thx but: (thisTouchTime - lastTouchTime) the first one is the time when the finger was up? the other one when the finger was pressed on the device?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been on here in a little while.  If this is in your render loop then thisTouchTime - lastTouchTime will simply be the interval between your refreshes.